# How to show the contents of first tab by default when using renderUI

Tags: r, shiny

I am using `renderUI` to load contents of tab item using `argonR` and `argonDash` package. The first tabItem is selected but it does not show the contents of it ("Tab1") by default. Check below reproducible example.

```
library(shiny)
library(argonDash)
library(argonR)

ui <- argonDashPage(
  sidebar = argonDashSidebar(id = "sidebar01",size = "md",background = "white",
    argonSidebarMenu(
      argonSidebarItem(tabName = "Tab1",icon = NULL,"One"),
      argonSidebarItem(tabName = "Tab2",icon = NULL,"Two")
    )
  ),
  body = argonDashBody(
    uiOutput("tabdata")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tabdata <- renderUI({
    argonTabItems(
      argonTabItem(tabName = "Tab1",p("Tab1")),
      argonTabItem(tabName = "Tab2",p("Tab2"))
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

If I click on "Two" and then again on "One", I can see the content but not when the page is loaded by default.

If I hardcode the tab items and don't render it dynamically using `renderUI` everything works fine.

```
library(shiny)
library(argonDash)
library(argonR)

ui <- argonDashPage(
  sidebar = argonDashSidebar(id = "sidebar01",size = "md",background = "white",
                             argonSidebarMenu(
                               argonSidebarItem(tabName = "Tab1",icon = NULL,"One"),
                               argonSidebarItem(tabName = "Tab2",icon = NULL,"Two")
                             )
  ),
  body = argonDashBody(
    argonTabItems(
      argonTabItem(tabName = "Tab1",p("Tab1")),
      argonTabItem(tabName = "Tab2",p("Tab2"))
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

I have tried using JS functions etc to load the contents but none of it helped me.